# Testcafe not running the test in chromium browser when they are in the background

Tags: testing, automated-tests, chromium, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am running some Testcafe e2e test on Chromium with concurrency = 4. The issue comes that all 4 browsers that testcafe opens are overlapped and the ones in the background dont run any test and freezes forever.

One of the concurrency that is on top of all 4 browsers will execute all the test and the other 3 concurrences will try to run 3 different test-fixtures without executing or starting any of the test.

I am running my test like

```
"testcafe \"chromium --disable-background-timer-throttling '--window-size=1200,700'\" src/tests -c 4 -reporter spec"
```

I have been checking that chrome can disable background browsers if `--disable-background-timer-throttling` is not disabled. Still having the same issue. Here is a discussion in the old Testcafe forum about this issue related with chrome https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2939 .

Any idea why Chromium is not executing my test in the background?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that a workaround is to run the chromium browser in a headless mode. This will prevent the background windows to not be working.